# ssh: how to send data request after send_data?

Tags: ruby

After openning a ssh session to the remote host and queued some data through send_data, how to really trigger the action to send out the data to the remote host? chan.send_request does not work in V2.0(e.g: chan.send_request "shell", nil, true ). A simple example will be very helpful!

```
Net::SSH.start('remotehost','user') do |session|
    session.open_channel do |chan|
    chan.send_data "..."
    chan.send_data "..."

    ???
```

Thanks a lot!
  Dan

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate a shell, try something like:

```
chan.request_pty do |ch, success|
  raise "Error requesting pty" unless success
  ch.send_channel_request("shell") do |ch, success|
    raise "Error opening shell" unless success
  end
end
```

If you want to see the output of your commands you need to register a handler:

```
chan.on_data do |ch, data|
  # work with output here
end
```

(or for standard error output use `chan.on_extended_data`)

Comment: Yes, the newline is attached to each send_data, but they are now executed.

Comment: @Dong Dan: I've rewritten my answer, hopefully it's a bit more helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan, it causes the "Error opening shell (RuntimeError)", will investigate again.